# Multiple sets backed by the same backing object

Tags: java

Im new to Java and need your help with a data structures problem.
Currently I have a scenario where I have a "set"/"list" of Objects.. lets say CARS. And CARS can have n number of subsets (Lets say that these subsets are by Manufacturing company - BMW/Audi/Toyota/Hyundai etc..), which can grow/shrink.

With above scenario, each and every time I add an object to CARS, this new object must also reflect in one of the subset (based on Manufacturer property).

How do I get this resolved? In "C" i could have utilized the pointer concept, but need help in achieving this in Java.

Comment: You could start with a `Map<Manufacturer, Set<Car>>` which, for each manufacturer, associates a number of cars.

Comment: Is `Manufacturer` the only subset you'll have, or you can have many different ones (type of vehicle, country of origin, engine types, etc)?

Comment: assylias.. thank you for the thought.. thats certainly a way of doing it.. but i have a scenario, which is possibly weird in the cars example.. where a "Toyota" car becomes a "Hyundai" due to an update on the "Toyota" set and with least possible overhead, i wanted to have the master copy updated, the updated car removed from Toyota set and added to the Hyundai set. Using MAPs, the problem is that the Object modifying "Toyota" set doesnt know about "Hyundai" set.

Comment: Laf.. the scenario currently doesnt exist at this point.